# How to implement GPS Status change listener in flutter

Tags: flutter, gps, listener

I was in a FLUTTER project that's related to OLA, UBER, so i need a stream function(like flutter GeoLocatior().isLocationServiceEnabled()) that notifies when user turns off location.

Comment: Both location and geolocator package does not have that functionality. You can simple create interval methods.

Comment: yeah i too encountered, so making interval is the only way ...?? through method channel....!!!

Comment: You don't need method channel, just create a interval for isLocationEnabled or any ready method from packages that's all. You can use Stream or Timer, it depends on your code structure.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **Location Permissions** package to achieve this.[location_permissions](https://pub.dev/packages/location_permissions#-installing-tab-)

```
Stream <bool> locationEventStream;
@override
void initState() {
 locationEventStream = LocationPermissions().serviceStatus.map((s) => s == ServiceStatus.enabled ? true : false);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder < bool > (
   stream: locationEventStream,
   builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active && snapshot.hasData) {
     if (snapshort.data) {
      //GPS on
     } else {
      //GPS off
     }
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: location_permissions package is deprecated now.

Answer (score 1):

[Geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) package has this functionality. It can be used same as below:

```
StreamSubscription<ServiceStatus> serviceStatusStream = Geolocator.getServiceStatusStream().listen(
    (ServiceStatus status) {
        print(status);
    });
```